# Ubuntu Vivid Android USB tethering not works

Tags: android, ubuntu-gnome, mobile-broadband

I have `LG G3 (32GB/3GB)` When I tried USB tethering with my Ubuntu vivid it connected but after about 20-30 seconds it disconnected. I tried with two laptop which are running Ubuntu vivid. And it refers to `Mobile Broadband` and `It shows me that you're now connected to home network` and then I created a new mobile connection but it also doesn't work or I couldn't make it with correct configuration.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I figured it out (though too late for you I guess, but might be useful for others)...so to pick up from where you are:

1. Leave the USB connected, but turn off USB tethering on the LG
2. In Ubuntu, on the network dropdown, unflag Enable Mobile Broadband
3. On the LG, re-enable USB tethering
4. In Ubuntu, again on the network dropdown, Auto Ethernet...

After 2 seconds, you should have the connection..